# OutOfMemoryError Java heap space when using timertask

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

This is weird: When I start a schedule using `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`, it takes a long time and then throws a `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, but if I just called the `timerTask.run()` method in the main thread, it works just fine.

The method I called is not open-source, so I cannot just paste it out. But could anyone help me analyse some possibilities on this scenario. What is the difference between running it in a timerTask thread and running it in the main thread?

Thanks a lot!

**The code snippet is just as simple as follows:**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask()  {
    @Override
    public void run()  {
        AModule.load(tmpFilePath);   //not open-source
    }
}
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, new Date(), 1*60*1000);  //OOME
//If I change the upper code to:
task.run()  //it just works fine
```

Comment: show your code, so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Trying to analyse code we can't see is a flawed premise.

Comment: Post some code for us. And maybe check for recursive calls or for memory-persistant instances (finish/close resources, big objects etc.).

Comment: At what rate did you schedule the task? Maybe it's too short and multiple tasks run in parallel. Did you analyze your heap dump (which you should tell the JVM to create on OOME)?

Comment: How to analyze my heap dump in eclipse? @Thomas

Comment: What else is your application doing?

Comment: Just this part, I wrote another main entry to call on this part, and it just did what I described above. @Taylor

Comment: How many runs of this do you get before it OOM's?

Comment: At the very first call on `AModule.load(tmpFilePath);` @Taylor

Comment: Install the MAT plugin or download standalone MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to analyze your heap dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWT timer runs in its own thread.  **If by "main thread" you mean the UI thread, or event queue, *then:***

Perhaps your closed source code is accessing Swing some how.  Swing components should only be accessed from the event thread.  You might have trouble when running in the timer yet always run fine in your main thread.

If that's the case you're lucky.  Calling Swing from another thread usually works.  I never have problems till I'm demoing or the client tries to use it.  And the problems are often not repeatable.

Comment: There are no `swing` bro. I just use spring and command line to run my code.

Comment: @Judking: worth a try.  Hmmm.  I still think the timer thread is the problem.  Are you running any other code on the main thread that might interact with the code you're running in the timer?  (Might not be thread safe?)  In particular, if code in your main thread sets a non-volatile field value outside a synch block, the code in the timer _will see the old value_.  Should be okay if it sets the value, then you start the timer, but if you start the timer then set the value, each thread _can_ have its own value.  (You need open source here!)

Comment: It's not that complicated, the test code is just almost the same as my code snippet above. Oh, here's some progress in this issue: When I set -Xmx1024M in VM arguments, it works fine when using timertask.